# iOS views and controls with source code and demo

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, demo

I'm looking for a bundle of demos with source codes to help me understand the apple technologies.
For Flash/Flex there is a very nice [Flex app](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex.html) that showcases all the Containers/Controls and [shows inline source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3oQw.jpg).
For Android, there is ApiDemos sample project + a lot more demos which come with the Android SDK. You can test them, preview them, change the source code etc...
I wonder whether there is something similar for iOS that I missed? It will be very helpful to me.
I know there are examples in the developer.apple.com, as well as github repos and tutorials over the internet. Is there something bundled with many demos using as little code as possible just to demonstrate quickly how a control is used? Something similar to the mentioned "Tour de Flex" and the Android SDK samples app?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I have found for this is the `UICatalog` project from Apple themselves. It showcases quite a lot of the standard UI components and how to use them.

[UICatalog from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

Of course, there are a lot of tutorials that deal with more specific things and custom things, but the best place to start is with the basics. You can expand from there.

Comment: Thank you, @SpacyRicochet. That is the closest thing to what I'm looking for. I wish there was sample code as well. For example, adobe documentation for flash has "Example section" for everything where you can copy-paste ready solutions to test them and taste how it's used.

Comment: You can download the sample code for everything on that page (little button in the top left corner of the main frame), which includes an Xcode project in Swift and an Xcode project in Objective-C. You can find the actual implementations there. I also found they have pretty good comments.

Comment: You are right! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. Altough there are not a lot of examples in there.. this is the most complete answer to my question. Thank you, @SpacyRicochet!

Answer (score 0):

The apple developer site http://developer.apple.com has lots of example source code you can download. There are also lots of sites that have tutorials and code downloads for them, like http://www.raywenderlich.com/.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I know there are examples in the developer.apple.com, as well as github repos and tutorials over the internet. Is there something bundled with many demos using as little code as possible just to demonstrate quickly how a control is used?

Answer (score 0):

check this out for latest IOS 7 UI new features usage Implementation, its awesome
https://github.com/shu223/iOS7-Sampler

Answer (score 0):

I have learned a lot from this.
http://www.appcoda.com/

Comment: this is a very nice site. I'm reading the book "Beginning iOS8 Programming with Swift" from the author of this website. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @plam4u you can also Refer This site : - http://www.ioscreator.com/

Comment: hey, @Aham iOS, I like your suggestions. Even though it's not exactly what I asked for, they are very very helpful. If you know more like ioscreator.com, I'll be glad to take your recommendations :)